# Can anyone explain the rationale of .NET's TryGetValue?

Tags: .net, collections

Can anyone tell me why the TryGetValue function on .NET generic collections sets the out value even when the lookup fails?

To my mind the whole reason we have TryGetValue is so that I can set an initial default/failure value and only have that value changed by the TryGetValue if the lookup actually succeeds. This is the *Try* part of the function. If I wanted undefined or exceptional behaviour when the lookup failed, I wouldn't be using *Try*GetValue.

The point of this function *should be* that it requires only one lookup internally where any other approach written external to the container will have to do the lookup twice in order to determine firstly if the value exists and secondly to retrieve it (setting aside using a try-catch).

If I use Dictionary as an example, lookup of the pair <3, 0> with TryGetValue(3, &local) returns 0 in local. Lookup in a map that doesn't contain any pair <3, x> returns 0. Lookup in an empty map returns 0. Too bad if 0 is a valid value that I want to store.

This means that if 0 is an acceptable return value, I have to manually reset the value to, say, -1, each time this fails. This may sound trivial but imagine the case where the default value (or any value) for a certain object takes a long time to construct...

Have I missed some obvious usecase where I would set my default value then WANT to have it overwritten by another that I can't choose?

Comment: As per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx): `When this method returns, contains the value associated with the specified key, if the key is found; otherwise, the default value for the type of the value parameter.`

Comment: Thanks Matt, I know that's WHAT they do, I want to know WHY.

Comment: You don't know why `out` parameters are explicitly set inside? Or you don't know why they used `out` parameter?

Comment: [Dictionary.TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) returns a `bool` that is set to `true` if the key was found; otherwise, `false`. Don't check whether the `out` parameter is set to 0 (or `default(T)`) or not; check the return value of the function.

Comment: @lila and Bradley - I know that it returns a boolean, I also understand that an out must be explicitly set within a function. The question is WHY a TryGetValue would not accept a ref which I can initialise to a 'non value' that makes sense in context.

Comment: LMFAO, closed just as we had raised a couple of intelligent points.

Answer (score 1):

`out` parameters have to be explicitly set within method declaring them. Naturally they are usually set to `default(T)`, which for `int` is 0.

Comment: That doesn't explain why they didn't use 'ref' instead of 'out' when designing it, though. 'ref' parameters do NOT have to be set before the method ends.

Comment: @NickAceves Why did they write the code the way they did? That is not an SO question, as discussions of this nature tend to lead nowhere.

Comment: @lila, if you're on stack overflow to use it as an alternative to your MSDN or whatever, that's fine. Some of us come here to discuss other things that are important to programmers though - such as design intentions and most efficient/correct usage of an API.

Comment: @DrefSkern have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/faq and the section on what kind of questions your shouldn't ask in particular.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that they did it so that you do not have to initialize the `out` parameter before calling the method.

They could have used `ref` instead. However, then the code below would be broken:

```
void Method() {
    int val;
    if(dict.TryGetValue("key", out val)) {
       Console.WriteLine(val);
    }
    return;
}
```

This code would produce a compile-time error if it used `ref` instead of `out`, since (per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)) `ref` arguments must be initialized before they are passed to a method.

Since this is a pretty common scenario when using `TryGetValue` (i.e., you want to try getting something from the collection, do something with it if it exists, and do nothing with it if not), it makes sense (to me at least) why they used `out` instead of `ref`.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I can see the argument here. I would hope that there's a better reason than supporting lazy code, but perhaps that's all it was. (In my mind I read your code and alarm bells go off because val is undefined at the end of Method, even though you're not returning it or anything.) This raises the further question of what happens with value types...

Comment: But that's just it, val *isn't* undefined at the end of the method, precisely because of the semantics of 'out'. 'out' requires that the callee give the argument a value, so you are guaranteed that after the call to TryGetValue, val has a valid value. There is simply no reason to initialize val prior to that - it's not lazy, it's a well-defined behavior of the language.

My example uses a value type - *int* is a value type. All types are set to their _default_ value (default(T)) inside TryGetValue.

Comment: We seem to have different meanings to the word 'assigned'. Assuming that we won't change for the default value of an int may be just fine in .NET (it certainly isn't in other languages) but it's still an assumption that isn't explicit in the code: could still shoot me in the foot when I later decide that 0 is a value I'd like to store. More to the point if I am doing a lookup that must return a value, it requires me to write several extra lines of code per lookup (whereas correct initialisation in your scenario would require very little extra work and cause the programmer to think carefully).

Comment: If you're using TryGetValue, then you are likely providing default behavior if the element doesn't exist anyways; that's the point. In this scenario, it doesn't matter whether the default value of an int is 0 or 1337 - as long as it's well-defined, you can do whatever you want when the key doesn't exist in the collection. That's why TryGetValue returns a bool - true if the key exists, false if not. If the value doesn't exist, you can then provide whatever your default behavior is, regardless of what the actual value of `default(int)` is. I don't see how this can shoot you in the foot at all.

Comment: I guess it comes down to the fact that we have two redundant and conflicting pieces of information being returned. If the boolean is false, not only do I require an extra clause but to manipulate the value a second time - because default initialisation may require no code but it still generates instructions... My collection never contained the value 0 but now it does, and the shot-foot moment is debugging that code years later and wondering why I'm returning a valid value when it isn't in the collection. Overall it still seems to me that using ref would result in better code in both scenarios.

Comment: PS The reason I mention (non-primitive) value types is that you cannot, for instance, simply declare KeyValuePair<int, int> myPair and then use the value - it will complain that this is uninitialised (just another reason not to assume every int starts with a value of 0).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You *absolutely can* instantiate a new `KeyValuePair<int, int>` and then access its `Value` property. It will be 0. I just tested it - it compiles and works just as I described (and expected). You can't declare ` `KeyValuePair<int, int>` variable and use it uninitialized, because it's a syntax error to access an uninitialized variable. The compiler prevents you from doing that. 

For example, the following code prints '0', just as one would expect:
            var x = new KeyValuePair<int, int>();
            Console.Write(x.Value);

Comment: I challenge you to get an uninitialized value type out of a method without using unsafe C# - I don't think you'll be able to, and that's why leaving variables uninitialized (or in this case, initialized inside a called method via an out parameter) isn't an issue - C# prevents you from not initializing variables and then trying to access or return them.

Comment: Heheheh OK, I'm not saying it's possible to get uninitialised variables in C#, I'm saying from a maintainability point of view having uninitialised variable declarations isn't cool - quite often you might define a constant for initialisations and the value of the constant might change - you pray it doesn't but they do. That's what's led me to spend so much time thinking about TryGetValue at the moment. ;-) Anyway we are way OT now... Will update question with code later...

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you should use the most restrictive method signature that is compatible with the method you are writing.  In the case of `out` versus `ref`, if you do not need need the caller to supply a value for a parameter, the method will be conceptually simpler if you use an `out` parameter instead of a `ref` parameter.  All things being equal, fewer inputs and fewer outputs are better.

This simplicity pays off in the readability of the code because the reader need not "look back" to see the logic of the previous lines of code in order to determine the incoming value of a parameter passed with a `ref` qualifier.

A different example might make the principle clearer.  It is sometimes more efficient to pass a parameter by reference than by value; this might be true for larger value types.  Take this method:

```
public Point3D Add(Point3D p1, Point3D p2)
{
    return new Point3D(p1.x + p2.x, p1.y + p2.y, p1.z + p2.z);
}
```

It might be tempting to add `ref` to each parameter like this:

```
public Point3D Add(ref Point3D p1, ref Point3D p2)
{
    return new Point3D(p1.x + p2.x, p1.y + p2.y, p1.z + p2.z);
}
```

but this sends the wrong message to the consumer calling our method that we might modify the parameters in the body of the method.  We are also trying to second guess the optimizer and the JIT compiler by assuming that passing by reference is more efficient.  It is better to have the code be clear and let the compiler do its job.

One might say, "Yes in that case, but that is different."  But the principle is the same: Prefer no qualifiers at all and prefer `out` to `ref` when a qualifier is needed.

In the case of `TryGetValue`, if the call is wrapped in an `if` such that the `out` parameter is not used when the condition is false, the method might in fact be inlined and the default constructor completely elided, which directly addresses the efficiency we were concerned about anyway.

As always, rules have exceptions.  If you really can prove a measurable performance gain by using parameter qualifiers that are not strictly necessary, you document the actual behavior, and accept the resulting loss of clarity, then it can be an acceptable trade-off for performance critical code.

Comment: The optimisation concerns are a good point, but I don't see the problem with sending the message that TryGetValue will change the value of the parameter - that's what I expect it to do. The fact that it's called *Try*GetValue is a big enough hint that in fact we want it NOT to modify the parameter if the lookup fails. Again consider the implications of returning 0 when this value isn't in the map - surely a more confusing behaviour than leaving a value unmodified.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get "undefined or exceptional behaviour" when the lookup fails: the value of the `out` parameter is set to `default(TValue)` and the method returns `false`. You're supposed to interrogate that return value to determine whether the lookup succeeded or not.

Admittedly, the use of an `out` parameter makes `TryGetValue` feel a bit clumsy (for example, having to declare the variable beforehand), but that's the established pattern. I suppose you'd need to ask Microsoft's BCL team if you want to know *why* that pattern was chosen in the first place.

Anyway, it's easy enough to "enhance" `TryGetValue` with some helper methods that do what you're expecting. (And if you're worried about the potential cost of creating the default value, you could have an overload that accepts a factory delegate and only creates the value if/when it's required.)

For example:

```
// pass the default value directly
int i = foo.GetValueOrDefault("answer", 42);

// pass a delegate to create the default value on-demand
var v = bar.GetValueOrDefault("costly", x => SomeExpensiveOperation(x));

// ...

public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(
        this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> source, TKey key, TValue defaultValue)
    {
        TValue value;
        return source.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? value : defaultValue;
    }

    public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(
        this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> source,
        TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> defaultFactory)
    {
        TValue value;
        return source.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? value : defaultFactory(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your wrapper idea, that's great and I may even use it (it's a small-medium project so not a lot of infrastructure but this could be a start). BTW All I meant by undefined or exceptional was that the other accessors on a Dictionary throw exceptions if the value is not found, leaving you with 'uninitialised' values (see lengthy discussion with Nick above).